# Regex nth match in equal string

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Is it possible to use only a regex (no additional code!) for matching the nth match? For example:

"CAR" - "TRAIN" - "BOAT" - "BICYCLE"

Now I only want to match the BOAT, regex for matching would be "[A-Z]+" however this also matches the first, second and fourth.

Does anyone have a pure regex solution for this? I need this because I can't change the code that uses the regex, but I can provide a regex.

Best regards,
Robin

Comment: So, what do you know about that code? It seems to use the global flag, but what regex flavours does it support?

Comment: Most regex flavours will support $N ($3 for "boat" in your case) for multiple matches.

Comment: It's a simple java regex using the Matcher. The first match is being used for further processing.

Comment: Can you redefine your problem to match the nth-to-last instead of the nth match?  Otherwise, you're stuck because Java has only limited support for lookbehind assertions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should do it:

```
(?<=^("[A-Z]+"[\s-]+){2})"[A-Z]+"
```

It matches a word that comes two words after the start of the string

[image]

Comment: A simple test using www.regexpal.com seems to fail? Is this due to the validator or the regex?

Comment: @RobinUS2: lookbehind is a complicated feature. JavaScript (at regexpal.com) does not support it at all, and [regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) doesn't seem to support repetition in the lookbehind expression.

Comment: @Bergi added screenshot from `RegexBuddy` at `.net` flavor. you are free to delete it you don;t want :)

Comment: @JohnWoo: Cool, thanks! would like to give that image an upvote :-)

Comment: @Bergi `+1` for you too, adding regex at lookbehind!

Comment: The only problem is that Java can't use this regex. Lookbehind assertions need to be finite in length in Java.

Comment: @TimPietzcker what do yo mean exactly?

Comment: @RobinUS2: Oh, does it work? That's interesting, because according to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), Java doesn't support indefinite-length repetition inside lookbehind assertions, so I would have expected that pattern not to compile.

Comment: I didn't have time to test it yet. I was more curious to the explanation you just gave.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right and you're putting multiple strings into one regexp, string by string, then **no**, this is **not possible**.

The regular expression itself does not have memory which lasts longer than matching time,
so if you're matching one thing and after that another thing, there's no information of the first.

Comment: It uses 1 line at a time, but needs to match the N-th word.

Answer (score 0):

(?!(\"[A-Z]*\"\s-\s){2})(\"[A-Z]*\") - where the {2} means which index you want.

The only problem with it is that it returns every match after the specified index as well. You could perform the match and return the first result.

Tested it using regexpal with your example.

Comment: Could you please post a permalink (see button at the bottom) to your regexpal test case; I can't really believe it matches